# why apache is enable to read file form cache?

Tags: apache-2.2

I am trying to enable cache on my apahce web server. I am using following module for this purpose.

```
LoadModule expires_module modules/mod_expires.so
```

I have added following lines in my `httpd.conf` file to set set the expire settings on the documents.

```
ExpiresActive On
ExpiresDefault "access plus 1 year"
```

By documentation, this should enable expiration on all the documents for one years, but when I test the application in firebug,

My index page sends 3 requests to server.

1. for a jpg image
2. for a gif image
3. for main jsp page.

But out of these three, only gif image is getting rendered from cache.I think this only a single file is rendered form cache, instead of all the other requests,

I am clueless about the matter, What do do? how should I enable the caching?

**Further Explorations**
I have looked into the headers returned by web server. There are expire header and also cache control header with max-age attribute, But still when i refresh the page, request goes to server to etch the data form.

Regrads,

`Vijay Shanker Dubey`